# Factors in page load time

Tags: wordpress, web, pagespeed, page-load-time

A website that I've created has a really poor page load speed which is due to multiple factors that I'm unsure of.

I did a test and here are the results.
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/mad.uk.com/n9gwWuLd

Can anyone help me with what the main issues are and what I can do to correct them?

Answer (score 0):

Main issues when you talk about a slow **WordPress** are:

- Bad Web Hosting, probably a shared hosting.
- Bad Plugins (or too many)
- Not optimized Theme
- External scripts
- No Cache plugin, for example, use plugins like W3 Total Cache
- No Content Delivery Network (CDN), for example, use CloudFlare
- No-optimized Images.
- No up to date WordPress/Plugins/Theme

Those are mainly the points that slow down most **WordPress**.

You can start by using [W3 Total Cache](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/w3-total-cache-settings/) and a [CDN](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-install-wordpress-cdn-solution-maxcdn/), that will help you a lot.

Comment: Please could you expand on solutions for optimizing a theme, external scripts and no content delievery network.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself I recommend you to start with the following things: check this [W3 Total Cache guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-install-wordpress-cdn-solution-maxcdn/) and also install a [CDN](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-install-wordpress-cdn-solution-maxcdn/)

Comment: Much appreciated